# PhD advisor making start up company based on my thesis work. How do I prevent this from delaying my graduation?

Tags: advisor, industry, patents

I am a fifth year PhD student who has independently developed a project for my thesis. Recently, I have presented some promising preliminary results. My professor called it a 'gold mine', and wants to start a company based on it. I prefer to publish it and make most of the data open source.

Today, my advisor hired a senior research scientist who intends to learn my work and start a company based on it. Apparently, they have been talking to each other for several months without my knowledge. The scientist intends on becoming CEO of this company and eventually wants equal inventorship, despite not having any experience in this field yet. My PI has made it clear that it is my responsibility to transfer the ideas and technologies that I have developed over to him before the end of my PhD.

I have argued with him that this work is not ready for a company, and such a start-up would rest on shaky foundations (I have not published or patented, or finished animal studies).

I also feel that he is holding my PhD degree ransom, as he has done more than once with other students in the past. He has a pattern of doing this with other students- hiring a 'CEO-type' senior research scientist to learn from a younger PhD student, working with the research scientist to start a company while the PhD student does most of the work, not allowing the PhD student to graduate until the company is off its feet, and then making millions selling the company, with minimal benefit or recognition to the student.

How should I approach this? Is there legal recourse and should I approach a third party? I have already discussed this many times with my PI, but he will not listen. I fear that my graduation will be delayed, andI would like to avoid burning any bridges.

Comment: Beyond the scope of my expertise, and would be great to get the input of others, but this seems like a situation where you need legal representation (perhaps from outside the university). This could be to 1) protect your intellectual property, 2) ensure you receive fair compensation (base % from VC funding, stock options, etc.), or any other potential outcomes...

Comment: You need to talk to the doctoral degree office. If they deny you help (which would be seriously unethical), you probably have no other chance to protect your IP rights than go legal. However, legal action will not help you gaining your PhD, be aware of that.

Comment: The intellectual property almost certainly belongs to the university.  There is no point in trying to "protect" it.

Comment: Patent your work yourself, start your own company, and tell him to screw off.

Comment: Seriously -- what gives him the right to force you to do this? You should start your own company. Use that same research scientist. Offer him a better deal than your advisor did.

Comment: I want to support Anonymous Phyicist at this one: unless you wrote all papers without any co-author, there is no chance you will get the property all to yourself.
Additionally, I wonder why this is actually a thing. Wouldn't it be much better for the professor if the one actually worked on it became CEO? In our department we have lots of those startups, but each one of them has a PhD as CEO who actually "invented" the idea.

Comment: How willing are you to burn bridges with your advisor? If you’re willing to do so, you could deliberately act to sabotage their new business by handing over the products of your research to somebody else associated with the university and then releasing everything you can open source. I wouldn’t be ask them for any letters of recommendation if you do, though.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: while the university (and not the prof!) does usually hold the transferrable IP rights, they may still be required to give a fair compensation to the inventor in case the company takes off. And e.g. in my legislation, the employer has to choose within a certain time frame whether they want to patent or not. If not IP would go to OP.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I approach this?

**Jump at the opportunity!** Your professor considers your work a "gold mine" and wants to commercialise. This is an extremely rare opportunity for any student and I recommend that you seriously consider embracing the opportunity. Let me consider some of your ideas and alleviate some of your concerns:

> I prefer to publish it and make most of the data open source.

This is a worthy academic goal, but it mightn't result in your desired outcome. Academics share results for others to build on, yet many results have no impact: If you're hoping your results will have impact, then why not make sure they do yourself? Keep the results private, build a company, make an impact.

> Today, my advisor hired a senior research scientist who intends to learn my work and start a company based on it...The scientist intends on becoming CEO of this company

Is there any reason to believe that this scientist should be CEO? As opposed to CTO, for instance? Why is the scientist even necessary? Consider taking the CEO role for yourself and maybe consider hiring the scientist.

Whether your supervisor should be involved is open for debate. They seem well-connected, so they could perhaps be very useful.

> [The senior research scientist] eventually wants equal inventorship

Inventorship (in terms of IP law) cannot be shared: An inventor has to have invented, they cannot come onboard. Perhaps you meant equal ownership?

> I have argued with him that this work is not ready for a company, and such a start-up would rest on shaky foundations (I have not published or patented, or finished animal studies).

You can start a company, strengthen the foundations, and patent the results. (NB: Your university may actually own the rights to any patents, it depends on your precise scenario. Regardless, you might not need to patent results that would be owned by the university, since patenting later results might suffice.)

Answer (score 0):

> My PI has made it clear that it is my responsibility to transfer the ideas and technologies that I have developed over to him before the end of my PhD.

That is correct.  These things almost certainly belong to the university.

> not allowing the PhD student to graduate until the company is off its feet

This is an inappropriate conflict of interest.  There is not much you can do about the conflict of interest.  But you can:

- Transfer all the information as you are obligated.
- Complete your thesis
- Obtain a job offer

If you have a job offer in hand which requires a PhD, it puts a lot of pressure on your supervisor to recognize that your thesis is complete.

Comment: Why must a PhD student _transfer...ideas and technologies_ to a third-party? (I agree that transfer to the university might be expected, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. Also, it is a little unclear who owns the IP, the OP wrote, _independently developed a project for my thesis_.)

Comment: @user2768 You are wrong, everyone mentioned in the question is affiliated with the university.  If it's for the thesis, most universities have a policy saying it belongs to the university.

Comment: I might be wrong, you most certainly are, and you seem to have chosen your words to mislead. We can assume a university exists, even though none is mentioned, since universities - exclusively, to my knowledge - award PhDs. So, everyone is _affiliated with the university_ (by proxy). Whether they are employed and what contractual obligations they have is unknown. Nonetheless, it's likely, but not certain, the OP and professor are employees. (It's plausible neither are.) It is unclear whether the senior research scientist is. We only know they've been hired, not by whom.

Comment: Assuming the senior research scientist isn't a university employee (which seems unlikely given that the professor is looking to commercialise), my question remains: Why must a PhD student _transfer...ideas and technologies [beyond the university]_? Regarding _a policy saying it belongs to the university_, that depends what the OP meant by _independently developed a project_. If the OP meant that the project was developed without university resources nor aid, then the project might belong to the OP. Admittedly, that's unlikely (which is why I wrote _a little unclear_).

Comment: No, @user2768, it is very obvious that "Senior Research Scientist" is a university employee.  They are not employed by the company that does not exist yet.

Comment: It isn't _very obvious_. Actually, it seems false. Indeed, searching a jobs site for "senior research scientist" produces twenty first-page hits, just two of which are (obviously) universities.

Comment: @user2768 That's not relevant.  "My advisor hired" is slang for "The university hired (and my advisor supervises)"

Comment: If that's true, then the advisor is failing to successfully commercialise: A university employee creates value for the university; not for a spin-off company. (The advisor may be trying to financially exploit the university, but that seems like a really bad idea.) The advisor should be hiring for the spin-off company to best exploit the OP's work.

Comment: @user2768 1.  The company does not exist yet.  2.  The university will own part of the company or part (all?) of the company's IP, so the advisor cannot prevent it from getting value out of the work.

Comment: (1) You know this how? (2) Attributing more IP to the university will reduce the company's value

Comment: @user2768 The company is described as future tense in the question.  I won't respond to you again.

Comment: The OP described the company in the future tense. The OP doesn't know what the advisor has been doing, as is apparent from the question. (I don't really have the will to continue this discussion. You have decided upon your position and you seem unwilling to reconsider, regardless of what may or may not be relevant.)